# Munmap isn't working

Tags: c, memory, malloc, mmap, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've a problem with munmap.
I'm implementing my own malloc/free. Malloc work fine, but free didn't.

Example (I directly use with a big munmap, because the code of my free is too long to be shown here):

```
#include "malloc.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char *addr;
    char *t;
    i = 0;
    while (i < 1024)
    {
        addr=(char *)my_malloc(1024);
        addr[0] = 42;
        if (i == 0)
            t = addr;
    //  my_free(addr);
    i++;
    }
    if (munmap(t, 1024*1024) != -1)
        printf("Ok\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When test it with /usr/bin/time -l ./a.out the number of page reclaimes is still the same, even if i remove the munmap.
So, I guess the munmap fail in an other way to unmap the pages..
But I don't understand at all where it could from.

Other example more easy :

```
# include <string.h>
# include <sys/mman.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char *addr;
    i = 0;

    while (i < 100)
    {
        addr =  (char *)mmap(0, getpagesize()*256, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON
        | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
        addr[0] = 42;
        munmap(addr, getpagesize()*256);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Always with /usr/bin/time -l ./a.out

With munmap or not, the number of pages reclaimes still is the same..

Any Idea ?

Thanks!

Edit : 
Always no Idea, I did some test, the memory is effectively disallocated, but the number of pages reclaimed is still the same.
I really don't understand ? Is it a bug from munmap ?

Comment: What do you mean by "number of pages claimed"? What does "claimed" mean in this context?

Comment: What does `time -l` do on your system? `-l` is not an option that exists for the standard gnu [time command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time). It's not clear that you are using the right technique for coming to your conclusions.

Comment: @AlanAu: /usr/bin/time is a standalone "measure the time" program, not the one built into the shell. It provides much more information than the actual time it took to run the code, and has several extra options.

Comment: @JeanYim: What exactly does `my_malloc` do? Your second example of "here I'm sure `munmap` works" is not doing quite the same as your first code. What is the measure of your second program if you run the loop once, with no `munmap`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz To me the number of pages claimed is the number of page allocated with mmap

Comment: @AlanAu It giving me a lot of information on the execution of my process, and the number of pages claimed by him

Comment: @MatsPetersson My_malloc allocate pool of memory for 3 category of syze (tiny, small, large)
I know is not doing the same at all, but that was for the example, the question was, why munmap doesn't work ? It should be

Comment: C or C++? Pick _one_...

Comment: @MatsPetersson @JeanYim Please provide a reference to the `time` command man page. I am aware of the standalone `time` command. But [that one](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) does not have an `-l` option AFAICS.

Comment: That's maybe because I'm under Yosemite (Osx)
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/time.1.html

Comment: @JeanYim Well then the answer to your question is obvious -- `munmap` has no effect on the number of pages allocated with `mmap`. Can you paste the output of `time`? I'm suspecting that it's printing out the maximum size, which `munmap` won't change.

Comment: @JeanYim: Since docs for `time -l` says it prints `rusage`, and looking at the rusage structure https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getrusage.2.html, there is nothing saying "current mmap usage". So I think you need to explain exactly which one of the fields you are actually looking at?